# How to lock device id's to port addresses?

Tags: linux, usb, path

I want to dedicate certain USB ports to certain devices. How can I do that?

For example: I want ttyUSB0 to be my mouse and ttyUSB1 to be my keyboard (always). I want to be certain that the startup of Linux never swaps them.

Acctually the thing is that I have XBee who usally goes to USB0 and a second FTDI that goes to USB1, for security reason I always want them to have the same address in my code I'm running.

Kind regards

Comment: Are you sure this is linux? In linux ttyUSBx are devices for USB serial terminals. Mouse & keyboard are HID-devices, watch for them in  /dev/input.

Comment: How could I possibly be mistaken of what OS I'm running? This is Debian on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The kernel-assigned names are always assigned in the order the devices are detected, and you cannot change them. (Not anymore, anyway – this function was removed due to various race conditions that "persistent name" rules caused.)

But you can tell *udev* to create **symlinks** with whatever names you choose. In fact, on modern systems, you should **already have** symlinks under `/dev/serial` named after both the device's path, and its unique ID; for example:

- `/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0` → `ttyUSB0`
- `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Motorola_Inc._Motorola_Phone__C350_-if00` → `ttyACM0`
- `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST9640320AS_5WX1ZH91-part1` → `sda1`
- `/dev/disk/by-partlabel/Arch` → `sda3`
- `/dev/input/by-id/usb-PIXART_USB_OPTICAL_MOUSE-mouse` → `mouse1`

And so on. Just **run `tree /dev`** or `ls -lR /dev` to find your device.

You can also run `udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0` and all symlinks to that device will be listed as `S: ...` lines.

---

If this is not enough, you can write your own udev rules. First run `udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0` and choose any identifying property (such as `ID_PATH` for the USB port). It's a good idea to always include the subsystem as well.

Then open (or create) a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` (named, for example, `serial-symlinks.rules`), and put the udev rule there.

For example, if the output for `ttyUSB0` is:

```
$ udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0
. . .
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0
. . .
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
. . .
```

...you can write this rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0", SYMLINK+="tty-xbee"
```

...and udev will always symlink `/dev/tty-xbee` to whatever tty device you connected to USB port #2.

---

(Note: **Do not** use the same names for symlinks as the kernel uses for device nodes. Using `SYMLINK+="ttyUSB0"` **will** cause bad things to happen.)

Comment: Excellent post! Thanks. Some time when I stop my code I note that XBee will change port from USB0 to USB1. I don't know the cause of this, but if I in my code instead of using path /dev/ttyUSB0 uses for example /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Motorola_Inc._Motorola_Phone__C350_-if00 this problem will be solved, right?

Comment: @Christian: Yes.

Comment: @grawity are the pci and usb port IDs under ` /dev/serial/by-path/` allocated according to the physical topology or according to a random (for any reason like parallel discovery) discovery order?

Comment: @JulioGuerra: They're supposed to represent physical topology (that's pretty much _the whole point_ of `by-path` over raw sequential `tty*` names). Note how the `pci` tag is followed by PCI domain:bus:slot.func, for example. /// That said, the physical topology can change too, if the firmware decides so – I've heard of a few PCs where the same physical PCI slot would get a different ID depending on whether other slots were filled... If that's also a concern, use `by-id` names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do with USB serial devices:

1. `cd /dev/serial/by-id`
2. `ls -l`

   For example:

   `root@toaster:/dev/serial/by-id# ls -l`

   `total 0`
   `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan  1  1970 usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A7035K2R-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0`
3. Make a symlink from this L-O-N-G name to a name of your choosing in a directory of your choosing.  In my case, it is a system device and only root controls it so I make a link in `/root`, like:

   ```
   ln -s /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A7035K2R-if00-port0 /root/easydigi
   ```
4. In your programs or whatever needs the device name of the serial device, you just use your link, in my case above "/root/easydigi", as the replacement for the "/dev/ttyUSB0".